# React-native-maps v0.20.1 with expo v25.0.0

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-maps

I am using expo v25.0.0 to develop mobile app with react native. my react-native version is the latest one. so the issue is that react-native-maps has react-native@0.51.0 and react-native@16.0.0 as dependencies while in my package.json, since my expo version is v25.0.0, I have react-native@0.52.0 and react-native@16.2.0 as deps.

so running the app I have this error:

```
peer dep missing: react@16.0.0, required by react-native-maps@0.20.1
peer dep missing: react-native@0.51.0, required by react-native-maps@0.20.1
```

someone can tell me what I am supposed to do please?

I found also this library: react-native-mapbox-gl, do you think that it can be a good alternative to use it instead of react-native.maps?

thank you

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need to bring in `react-native-maps` separately if you want to use them with `Expo`. `Expo` has that library already built in.

Here's all you need to import the `MapView`, straight from the `Expo` documentation:

(They provided some sample coordinates for the lat/lng in the `initialRegion`, but you can obviously change these to whatever you'd like.)

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/map-view.html

```js
import React from 'react';
import { MapView } from 'expo';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MapView
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        initialRegion={{
          latitude: 37.78825,
          longitude: -122.4324,
          latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
          longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually it is working but I still have the warning (not blocking one). because react-native-maps depends on other older versions of react and react-native.